# Determining the roots of polynomial $R(x)$

Tags: polynomials

$$P(x) = x^2 -1 $$

$$R(x) = P(P(x))$$

- Determine the roots of the polynomial $R(x)$. ($1$, $0$ or $-1$)

**My Attempt:**

$$x^2-1 = 0$$

Rewriting the equation as

$$(x+1)(x-1)=0$$

Which yields two solutions

$$x = -1 \space \lor \space x = 1 $$

However, the correct root seems to be $0$. Can you explain why?

Regards!

Comment: You are asked to find solutions from a set of three choices. On such an occasion the method of trying them out in sequence is often fast: A) $P(0)=-1$ so $R(0)=P(-1)=0$ meaning that $x=0$ works, B) $P(1)=0$ so $R(1)=P(0)=-1$ meaning that $x=1$ does not work. C) leaving it to you check what happens with $x=-1$.

Comment: In other words, you need to review the meaning of *composition of functions*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$R(x) =P(P(x))$

$R(x) =(x^2-1)^2-1$

$R(x) = x^4+1-2x^2-1$

$R(x) = x^4-2x^2$

now:

$R(x)=0\implies x^2(x^2-2)=0$

$\implies x=0,\pm\sqrt2$

Answer (score 2):

$$R(x)=0\iff P(P(x))=0\iff P(x)=\pm1\iff x^2-1=\pm1$$
so we get $x=0$, $\sqrt2$ or $-\sqrt2$.